# how to increase fps of yolov3 on raspberry pi 4

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, opencv

I'm currently doing real time object detection with the help of pi camera using pre-defined weights of darknet and coco dataset using openCV. Currently I'm getting 0.14 fps and my video is too much laggy. is there anyway that I could increase my fps >=20 or to some value where video is not too much laggy.

I'm using raspberry pi 4 model B with 8Gb Ram.

Answer (score 0):

YoloV3 uses Darknet 53 as its backbone which is pretty heavy for a Raspberry. Maybe consider using another backbone like [TinyYoloV3](https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet/blob/master/cfg/yolov3-tiny.cfg)

Comment: i need accuracy in my object detection that's why i chosed yolov3 and not yolov3 tiny

Comment: Well its a trade-off between accuracy and detection speed. Maybe lower the resolution of the video if you increased the input size of your Yolo algorithm.

Comment: can you tell me how to lower resolution?

Comment: Here's some things you can do https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/94698/how-to-increase-fps-for-raspberry-pi-for-object-detection I've never had to lower resolution with a camera so I can't help with that sorry

Comment: You could get a faster computer. A high-end mini PC would cost between $500 - $900. A tradeoff of money vs speed.